# Django stuck on login page

Tags: python, django

I'm very new to Django and I am trying to create an Inventory app. The front page should be a login page and after login it should get data from the Model that I created through admin, But after running server it keeps heading back to login page all the time.

My Inventory(Project)- urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'^myapp/', include('myapp.urls')),
url(r'^home/', include('myapp.urls')),
]
```

My myapp urls.py-

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth.views import login

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^home/$', views.home, name='home'),
url(r'^$', login, {'template_name': 'myapp/login.html'}),
]
```

and in my setting.py of Project-

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home/'
```

After logging in it keeps going back to login page only!

Comment: Because /home/ *is* your login page. If you want to redirect somewhere else after logging in, you should put that URL in instead.

Comment: Your login page _is_ `home/` in this case, which is why you are constantly getting redirected here. To solve this, change the `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` to where you actually want to redirect.

Answer (score 1):

After login, you're redirected to `/home` which runs `url(r'^$', login, {'template_name': 'myapp/login.html'}),` and that's why you are constantly redirected to login view.

To solve your issue, try the following:

Project urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from django.contrib import admin

from myapp.views import home

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^home/', home, name='home'),
    url(r'^myapp/', include('myapp.urls')),
]
```

myapp urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth.views import login

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', login, {'template_name': 'myapp/login.html'}),
]
```

Comment: How do I define home as a view or create a template for it then? As I get an error that   url(r'^home/', home, name='home'),
NameError: name 'home' is not defined

Comment: You need to add `home` view to `myapp/views.py` file with some template.